# Make column length the max length of a column in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I want to do is something like this:

```
USE [database]

ALTER TABLE Client
    ALTER COLUMN CLientNameShort NVARCHAR(SELECT MAX(LEN([database].dbo.Sites.Sitename))
```

I would also like to TRIM the columns if they exceed a certain length, so it would set the max length of the column to the maximum value in the other database unless the max column exceeds 500 characters etc. If it does exceed 500, that column is trimmed to 500.

Is this possible?

Regards

EDIT:

So have ended up with this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alterFieldSize 
     @column NVARCHAR(MAX), @table NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    -- DECLARE VARIABLES
    DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @fieldLen   INT
    DECLARE @columnLen  INT

    -- SET VARIABLES
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE Client ALTER COLUMN ' + @column + 'NVARCHAR('+cast(@fieldLen as varchar(20))+')'
    SET @fieldLen = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.Sitename)) 
                     FROM [database].dbo.Sites s)
    SET @columnLen = (SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
                      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                      WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @column AND TABLE_NAME = @table)
    SET @fieldLen = CASE 
                       WHEN @fieldLen < @columnLen 
                          THEN @columnLen 
                       WHEN @fieldLen <=500 
                          THEN @fieldLen 
                       ELSE 500 
                    END

    -- Execution
    EXEC(@sql)
```

And calling the procedure like this:

```
EXEC alterFieldSize @column = 'ClientNameShort', @table = 'Client';
```

The command runs successfully but it doesn't actually change the maximum length of the columns.

Any ideas?

Comment: *maximum value in the other database* Do you mean the max value in records or Datatype size of column in other database

Comment: by maximum value i mean the largest value in another database, the data is going to be inserted into the database that i want to change the field lengths for, hence why i want to change the length of each field. The problem is that some of the fields are 8000 characters in length because people decide to put someones life story into an address field. So i want to trim those ones if they exceed a maximum field limit which will most likely be 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the value first.  Then, I think you'll need dynamic SQL for the `alter table`.  So:

```
declare @len int;

select @len = max(len(s.Sitename))
from [database].dbo.Sites s;

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'alter table client alter column ClientNameShort nvarchar(@len)';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@len', @len);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this query just hangs. It didnt run initially until i changed the second line to:

Comment: SELECT @fieldLen = MAX(LEN(s.SiteName)) FROM [database].dbo.Sites s;

Comment: You are correct, i am logged in as SA. This is a newly restored database with nothing in that table as of yet. For some reason i am getting the error: Cannot use the special principal 'sa' (Error 15405) when trying to add myself as dbowner for this DB it works for every other database i have on here...

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic sql to do this

```
Declare @sql varchar(max),
        @len int

set @len = (select MAX(LEN(Sitename)) from [database].dbo.Sites)

set @len = case when @len <=500 then @len else 500 end

SET @sql ='ALTER TABLE Client ALTER COLUMN CLientNameShort NVARCHAR('+cast(@len as varchar(20))+')'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Hi this also hangs, i let it run for 5 minutes and cancelled it.

Comment: @OwainEsau May be table is locked. Did you check for any locks ? How many records present in client table ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use COL_Length to get a length of column

```
   set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE Client ALTER COLUMN CLientNameShort NVARCHAR('+LTRIM(col_length('database.dbo.Sites','Sitename'))+')'
   EXEC(@sql)
```